# Is there a Pythonic way of truncating a Unicode string by a maximum number of bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

If an API accepts some string value with limit on a number of bytes, but accept Unicode, is there a better way to shorten the string with valid Unicode?

```py
def truncate(string: str, length: int):
    """Shorten an Unicode string to a certain length of bytes."""
    if len(string.encode()) <= length:
        return string

    chars = list(string)
    while sum(len(char.encode()) for char in chars) > length:
        chars.pop(-1)

    return "".join(chars)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You are using the world "byte", but Unicode has characters (or codepoints). Do you want to have a fixed length in characters? Or you need a fixed length in byte (but so, it depends on the encoding, do you mean UTF-8?) In this case the solution may be tricky. Is the length long?

Comment: What you are asking for is not very "Unicode-onic" :-). That is, it does not consider complexities of cutting short strings in various different language which Unicode supports. Read about ["Characters versus Glyphs" in Unicode TR#17 *Unicode Character Encoding Model*](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr17/#CharactersVsGlyphs). The simple truncation may leave you with badly-formed byte sequences or with glyphs damaged by missing characters. If you specify the glyph behaviour you want, then we can give you better answers on Pythonic ways to get it.

Comment: In this particular case I don’t care, Sendgrid is lying about accepting 50 chars for first/last name, when it’s 50 bytes. In DB we have up to 128 chars, so we have to cut it somewhere. That being said, if there a cleaner solution, please let’s hear it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work in Python-3:

```py
bytes_ = string.encode()
try:
    return bytes_[:length].decode()
except UnicodeDecodeError as err:
    return bytes_[:err.start].decode()
```

Basically we truncate at the first decoding error.UTF-8 is a prefix code. Therefore the decoder should always be able to see when the string is truncated in the middle of a character. Weirdness may occur with accents and stuff. I have not thought this one through. Maybe we need some normalization, too.

In Python-2, make sure to specify the encoding.

Comment: This should probably explicitly name the encoding. It defaults to UTF-8 on most sane platforms, but there are many users who use Windows because they don't know any better, or because they have to.

Comment: @tripleee In Python 3, .encode() and .decode() default to 'utf8' on Windows as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, characters/code points don't correspond with graphical units either.  This will work fine in most cases, but may break a combining character from its base unit, or split an emoji/flag sequence or similar.  That might be an acceptable limitation.  Using normalization will help remove some combining characters if available.

Comment: I am upvoting this because it is a fairly Pythonic way to cut off a string of Unicode text, encoded as UTF-8, at less than or equal to a limit in bytes. However, this kind of arbitrary cutoff is not very "Unicode-onic" :-) . See comment about character and glyph model under the main question.